# Defining a dictionary with a very large amount of columns

Tags: python, dictionary, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset that I want to move to spark sql. This dataset has about 200 columns. The best way I have found to doing this is mapping the data to a dictionary and then moving that dictionary to a spark sql table.

The problem is that if I move it to a dictionary, the code will be super hacky and not robust. I will probably have to write something like this:

```
lines = sc.textFile(file_loc)
#parse commas
parts = lines.map(lambda l: l.split(","))
#split data into columns
columns = parts.map(lambda p:{'col1':p[0], 'col2':p[1], 'col3':p[2], 'col4': p[3], ;'col5': p[4], 'col6':p[5], 'col7':p[6], 'col8':p[7], col9':p[8], 'col10':p[9], 'col11':p[10], 'col12':p[11], 'col13':p[12]})
```

I only did 13 columns since I didn't feel like typing more than this, but you get the idea.

I would like to do something similar to how you read a csv into a data frame in R where you specify the column names into a variable and then use that variable to name all columns.

example:

```
col_names <- ('col0','col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7','col8','col9','col10','col11','col12','col3')
df <- read.csv(file_loc, header=FALSE, col.names=col_names)
```

I cannot use a pandas data frame since the data structure is not available for use in spark at the moment.

Is there a way to create a dictionary in python similar to the way you create a data frame in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) might help.

```
dict(zip(col_names, p))
```

You can use [izip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) if you're concerned about the extra memory for the intermediate list.

Comment: the statement: dict(zip(['a','b','c'],[1,2,3])) produces the output:
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2} Why is the order not preserved?

Comment: you can use an ordereddict if you care about order